# Displaying full e-mail adress or just using the link name Mail

Tags: email, hyperlinks

Sometimes when you design contact information for people, in say a grid, you stumble upon individuals that have very long e-mail addresses. You could solve this by using extra-large space for e-mail or shrink long texts, but that makes it usually visually unpleasing.

Instead, you could just use an anchor link that says "Mail", next to the name. The argument I hear against this approach is that some people wish to copy and paste the full e-mail address into their e-mail app.

Should one display the full e-mail address or just use an anchor link that says Mail? Is there any research on how inconvenient this approach is?

Comment: On all smartphones, where the email icon is, the option to copy the address appears when pressing and holding it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about any research on this but I like how MS Teams handles this:

You could use an anchor link in addition to adding a copy icon next to it?

[image]